# extract audio from certain files in working dir in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Basically, what I'm trying to do is extract the audio from a set of downloaded YouTube videos, the names of which are (partially) identified in a file (mus.txt) that was opened with the handle `TXTFILELIST`. `TXTFILELIST` contains one 11-character identifier for the video on each line (for example, "dQw4w9WgXcQ") and the downloaded file is of the form [title]-[ID].mp4 (in the previous example, "Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp4").

```perl
#snip...
if ($opt_extract_audio) {
    open(TXTFILELIST, "<", "mus.txt") or die $!;
    my @all_dir_files = `dir /b`;
    my $file_to_convert;
    foreach $file_to_convert (<TXTFILELIST>) {
    my @files = grep("/${file_to_convert}\.mp4$/", @all_dir_files); #the problem line!
    print "files: @files\n";
    foreach $file (@files) {
        system("ffmpeg.exe -i ${file} -vn -y -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 ${file}.wav");
     }
     }
#snip...
```

The rest of the snipped code works (I checked it with several videos, replacing vars, commenting, etc.), is legal (I used the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas) and, I believe, is irrelevant, because it has nothing to do with defining any vars (besides `$opt_extract_audio`) used in this snippet. However, this is the one bit of code that's giving me trouble; I can't seem to extract the files that are identified in `TXTFILELIST` from `@all_dir_files`. I got the code for 'the problem line' from other Stack Overflow answerers, but it isn't working for some reason.

TL;DR What I want to do is this: list all files in the current dir (say the directory contains mus.txt, "Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp4", and blah.mp4), choose only the identified file(s) (the Rick Astley video) using the 11-char ID in `TXTFILELIST` (dQw4w9WgXcQ) and extract the audio from it. And yes, I am running this script on Windows, so I can't use *nix utilities like `ack` or `find`.

Comment: ack comes with Perl, I run it on my win32 box.  I also run many Unix utilities that have been compiled for win32 including find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line

```
my @all_dir_files = `dir /b`;
```

And use this loop instead:

```
for my $file (<*${file_to_convert}.mp4>) {
    say $file;
    system(...);
}
```

The `<...>` above is a glob, can also be written `glob "${file_to_convert}.mp4"`. I think it is almost always better to use perl functions rather than rely on system calls.

As has been pointed out, `"/${file...$/"` is not a regex, but a string. And since you can use expressions with grep, and a non-empty string is always true, your grep will essentially do nothing, and pass all the values into your array.

Comment: I'm not sure that is going to work, the $file_to_convert variable is misnamed, it is just part of the file name, a suffix, but it is not a pattern.  The OP does a tail anchored match of this suffix plus .mp4 to get all of the files in the group.  Your glob needs a "*-" at the front, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the double quotes around the regular expression in the grep function.